# Can I use Azure Active Directory B2C to authenticate with both SQL Database user table and ADFS via SAML?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory

The company I work for have a requirement where a client would like to login to our .Net Core 3.1 azure based web app with their on premise active directory (ADFS) via SAML. After taking a look at various options online, I found that Azure Active Directory B2C seemed to fit the bill.

However, the app also needs to authenticate against an Azure SQL Database User table. After looking through various articles and sample applications, it doesn't seem that Azure AD B2C can support authentication against a custom DB. Can anyone confirm that I am right in thinking this?

If B2C cannot support this, can anyone suggest a workaround using B2C instead? If not, would Azure AD fit the bill better, or maybe an alternative like IdentityServer? The only reason I didn't go ahead with IdentityServer initially was because we already have an Azure subscription and IdentityServer's support for version 4 ends in Novemeber 2022 when it becomes a fully commercial product - and I believe it only supports SAML with the help of a paid [plugin](https://www.identityserver.com/products/saml2p). If this is our only option we will of course have to bite the bullet but it would be good if we could work around this issue using Azure.

Answer (score 0):

B2C will indeed allow you to define custom authentication policies and integrate with the customers ADFS, but it will not allow you to delegate their authentication token to a SQL backend which relies on your own Azure Active Directory.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-adfs?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-user-flow

I appreciate your approach to implementing best practices with data access controls, but I think in this case you're going to need to implement authorisation controls in your application, rather than at the SQL level.  Your best bet is to use a service principal for the app, and grant this principal all the necessary access to the database that it would possibly need.

More on token delegation to SQL can be found in this great blog post by Tomas Restrepo:

https://winterdom.com/2017/08/31/token-delegation-azure-sql

Unless you are willing to invite the customer's users to be guests in your Azure AD (B2B), you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

> it doesn't seem that Azure AD B2C can support authentication against a custom DB. Can anyone confirm that I am right in thinking this?

A while back I planned out a migration from a bespoke/back-end auth solution (where username & (hashed) password were stored in an on-prem Oracle an DB) to Azure AD B2C.

We implemented a JIT migration to B2C and orchestrated this in IEF (Identity Experience Framework), which is an XML-based DSL for B2C. We got it all working, but it was a bit of a painful experience. We needed an on-prem APIs to support the JIT migration and the team found IEF a bit tricky to work with. Unfortunately the project got squashed (for unrelated/unforeseen reasons) during delivery, but I can say that it should be possible to do what you want.